# How to distinguish between app fresh start vs app resumed from background

Tags: android

I have some code I need to execute once when the user launches the app. setting it in onStart/onResume will lead to it being executed also when the app goes to background and then to the foreground again. I did try using a static boolean set as true and then I set it to false once the code is done but I ended up having a bunch of these booleans which doesn't look nice. Is there a better approach to solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put your specific code when user start the app for the first time in `onCreate()` method and not in `onStart()` or `onResume()` because both are used when application is resumed again .

Read [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity) about android life cycle

Comment: That'll work in my case because i have a single activity and it being destroyed means closing the app right

Comment: maybe i didnt make it clear but i need that code to only be done one time through the app's life

Comment: you should use onCreate in every activity ,and the main activity of your app will always remain at the top of the activity stack

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extends `Application()` override `onCreate()` and execute your code inside it.

```
import android.app.Application

class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Your code here
    }
}
```